# Searching word by its part

Tags: search, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write a program which searches all the "words" of a list by searching for given substring. E.g.: `(monday thursday friday)` *search "ida"* = friday.

Something like this:

```
(nth iday '(monday hello sup friday))
```

but it keeps marking error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please show your code and the error. No one here can tell what your problem is until you show the necessary information

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place where people do your homework just like that. Show your effort, your thoughts about the way your problem could be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression makes no sense. [`nth`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm) is for accessing element by index.

You can use [`remove-if-not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) to get only matching strings from your list:

```
(defun find-matching-substr (substr-sym list-of-symbols)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (sym)
                   (search (string substr-sym)
                           (string sym)))
                 list-of-symbols))

CL-USER> (find-matching-substr 'day '(monday hello sup friday))
(MONDAY FRIDAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit overkill if you only have one continuous substring. But as soon as you want to find more complicated matches [cl-ppcre](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) (a regexp library) comes to mind. It is available via [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) and well documented. Bear in mind though that apply `string` to a symbol will return the symbol name in [capital letters](http://www.cliki.net/case%20sensitivity).

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")

(defun find-matching-substr (regexp list-of-symbols)
  (remove-if-not #'(lambda(sym)
             (cl-ppcre:scan regexp (string sym)))
         list-of-symbols))


;;looking for strings containing ida
(find-matching-substr "(i?)ida" '(monday tuesday thursday friday saturday))
(FRIDAY)

;;look for strings starting with f and ending in y
(find-matching-substr "(?i)f.*y" '(monday tuesday thursday friday saturday))
(FRIDAY)

;;look for strings containing exactly 3 vowels
(find-matching-substr "^([^AIEOU]*[AIEOU]){3}[^AIEOU]*$" 
                      '(monday tuesday thursday 
                        friday saturday sunday 
                        anotherday dayafterantother))
(TUESDAY SATURDAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp includes a **find** function, as well as a case insensitive **char-equal** function, and a function **search** that finds an occurrence of a sequence within another sequence.  Thus you can do:

```
(find "iday" '(monday hello sup friday)
      :test (lambda (part whole)
              (search part whole :test 'char-equal))
      :key 'string)
;=> FRIDAY
```

The **:key** argument gets applied to each element of the list, so you get `"MONDAY"`, `"HELLO"`, etc., and you're searching for an element that satisfies the **:test** function.  The **:test** function uses **search** to look for an occurrence of `"iday"` in the list element.  The **:test** argument to **search** (**char-equal**) ensure that the elements are compared case insensitively.  Thus:

```
(defun find-word (word words)
  (find (string word) words
        :test (lambda (part whole)
                (search part whole :test 'char-equal))
        :key 'string))
```

```
(find-word 'iday '(monday hello sup friday))
(find-word "idAY" '(monday hello sup friday))
;=> FRIDAY

(find-word "IDAY" '(monday hello sup "friday"))
(find-word 'iday '(monday hello sup "friday"))
;=> "friday"
```

Comment: 'all the "words" of a list...' - I think OP wants to return several items in a list, in case if there're more than one symbol that contains given sub-string, although it's not completely clear anyway.

Comment: @Mark It's possible, but the title isn't "searching for words by their parts", and the example is "search Ida '(...) = Friday", not "search Ida '(...) = (Friday)".